# How to prevent a record from being deleted in account object when rating is set to hot?

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger Tour on Account (before insert ) {
Account sam=Trigger.new[0];
    if(sam.Rating=='Hot' )
    {
        sam.AddError('record cannot be deleted');
    }
}
```

Even though when I run this
record is deleting.

can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to write trigger on before delete. Also, look into context variables.

```
trigger Tour on Account (before delete) 
{
    if(Trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(Account act:Trigger.old)
        {
            if(act.Rating=='Hot' )
            {
                act.addError('Record cannot be deleted');
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

**Update based on comments**

Account Record

[image: Account]

Error during delete

[image: validation error]

Comment: `Trigger.isDelete &&` is not necessary.

Comment: not necessary, actually we follow single trigger per object design, that's why I kept it

Comment: If you're going to argue that, the Trigger.isDelete should be outside the for loop for performance reasons.

Comment: that't true, I have updated my answer

Comment: even though, when i run your code the record is getting deleted @SantanuBoral

Comment: Debug it properly and check rating value, it should work

Comment: No @SantanuBoral, i tried everything 
its not working !!!

Comment: @jamesandy, this code is working perfectly, surely you are missing something, check my answer with screenshots from my DE. Make sure trigger is active and it satisfies the condition

Comment: @SantanuBoral thank you for the answer
i have a doubt. Why did you use Trigger.old in the code ? What does it exactly do ?

Comment: Trigger.old is the context variable which holds records to be deleted. This sObject list is only available in update and delete triggers. Read this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm